# Proving this homomorphism has a nontrivial kernel

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Given: $|G|=n$, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $|G/H|=k$, where $n$ does not divide k!.

WTP: The left action map on $G/H$ has a nontrivial kernel.

I have not put the entire problem I am trying to work on here, just the part I am stuck on. I think this should be true, but I am having trouble showing nontriviality. I know if we take an element of  G/H then the kernel of the map are all elements a such that $agH=gH$, but I cannot prove that there are any $a$'s that will do this other than the identity. Can anyone help, or tell me if this is not true?

Comment: Work this out with $S_3$ and a subgroup of order $2$.

Comment: The kernel are all elements $a$ such that $agH=gH$ for *every* $g$, i.e., the intersection of the stabilizers.

Comment: I'm sorry I mistyped, n should not divide k!, obviously it does not divide k,k-1,k-2,...,1. I have modified the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The left action map of $G$ on $G/H$ induces a homomorphism $\phi: G \to S(G/H) \simeq S_k$, given by $a \mapsto \{gH \mapsto agH\}$.

The kernel of the action is the kernel of this homomorphism. If the kernel were trivial, then $\phi$ would be injective, giving an embedding of $G$ as a subgroup of $S_k$. Why can't this happen?

Comment: I think the homomorphism I am looking at is G/H on phi(G/H), would that be any different? Also, I have figured out what the kernel would be, but I am having difficulty proving the kernel is necessarily nontrivial, which I would assume follows from the second given, that n does not divide k!. Do you know how to prove nontriviality? Or maybe this is an obvious fact? As stated above, the overall question is actually a lot more than what I wrote, this is just one step of it that I am having trouble with.

Comment: No idea what you mean by "I think the homomorphism I am looking at is..."; remember that $G/H$ is *not* necessarily a group. The induced homomorphism I speak of is given by $a \mapsto \{gH \mapsto agH\}$. What can be said about this homomorphism if the kernel is trivial?

Comment: It means it is injective, is that what you are going for?

Comment: If the kernel is trivial, then the map *is* injective. I assume that's what you meant to say, and yes.

Comment: But I want the kernel to be nontrivial, so you are saying that what I said above is not true?

Comment: I guess? I'm saying use proof by contradiction; if the kernel is trivial, then the map is injective. Note also that $|S_k| = k!$.

Comment: Ah ok, let me go back to the drawing board then. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @MathStudent See my edit; I've made it a little more explicit.